# Save use in a sentance

Tags: meaning

when a person says: I am clear on Tuesday save between 9-10am and 3 -4pm. Is this person available in those time or NOT available?

Answer (score 2):

The Cambridge dictionary has [this definition of 'save'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/save):

> but or except (for)

So the person is clear on Tuesday *except* between 9-10am and 3 -4pm

Comment: Thank you, I asked a few native English speakers -  I got different answers

Comment: A good dictionary will often help.